# How to restore acl policies using importXML in apache jackrabbit?

Tags: apache, acl, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I am developing an apache sling WCMS. I export a subtree of the repository contents to an xml file using `session.exportSystemView(...)`  and it works perfectly.

When I restore the xml file, using `session.ImportXML(...)` all of data back completely except access control entries set on the nodes in the subtree and `jcr:policy` nodes have no child.

I want to know how to restore all of data with their jcr policies.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding `ProtectedNodeImporter` configuration to `workspace.xml`
as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace name="default">
  ....

    <Import>
        <ProtectedNodeImporter class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.xml.AccessControlImporter"/>
    </Import>
</Workspace>
```